# CSS Div with fixed height and automatic width

Tags: css, height, width, fixed

so i want to make a div container, which i give a fixed height and want that it automatically fit its width to the content in it, even if it is over 100% of the screen width.
Simply by declaring width:auto on the css of the div won't work, because it's not becoming bigger than 100% of the screen.

```
.container {
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;   
}
```

Here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/8MqtN/2/

Comment: If you want a div to encompass an entire width, simply do not add a width property to the CSS. I see no issue in your fiddle. Perhaps you haven't explained the issue well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following css for your body and try once and see if you get what you want .

```
      body
          {
          margin : 0;
          padding: 0;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of width try using `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

I just added to your css class .container

```
position: relative; display: table;
```

Now your content seems to be aware of the the height of your content. The red background you set expands accordingly to the content inside. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I see you want expanding width not height.. I'm trying below suggestions for display: inline-block;, that isn't working for me.. I'm playing with more things... un momento por favor

Comment: What if you added,

td { float: left; width: 100%: }

that should expand each block 100% of the available viewing area